# Clearing select field using jquery but with rendering problems

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, select

I have a select field with the id being `node_service_area_city`. I wish to clear this dropdown using jquery. For the same I have the following code:

```
$("#node_service_area_city").empty();
```

When this line is commented I can chose any of the options in the dropdown. When the code is run with this line included then the options in the dropdown are STILL THERE but I cannot chose any of them. Nothing happens if I click on any of the options.

As such I feel that the dropdown menu is empty but somehow the dropdown items are still showing so I might have to refresh the page. Someone please guide me as to why this is happening and what can I do about it.

Comment: Do you want to unselect any selected option or remove all the options?

Comment: This sounds like a browser rendering bug. Can you provide a fiddle showing the problem. `empty()` should be fine for this purpose; I've used it myself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/f8LLecLh/1/ ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try this :

```
$('button').click(function () {
    $("#node_service_area_city > option:first-child").prop("selected","true")
});
```